# ASP.NET Core SignalR Hub call from Hangfire Server Job

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr, hangfire, asp.net-core-signalr

Suppose I have two projects:

- ASP.NET Core Web API, which serves for frontend React application and uses Jwt Bearer authentication scheme.
- ASP.NET Core Hosted Hangfire service with queues

Expectation:
Web API project has SignalR Core Hub which sends Notifications to React Frontend when Hangfire Job is finished. So I need some way to call hub from Hangfire job. For this task I found **Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client** and I could easily create client connection and call hub hosted in WebAPI project.

This is visual representation of desired outcome:
[image]

However, my main consideration is Authentication concern:

for Frontend and Hub connection I use Jwt Bearer tokens (hub has [Authorize] attribute and ASP.NET Core manages Authentication pipeline itself).

So in order to call this hub from .NET Core SignalR Client in Hangfire project I would need to pass token, so I would need some sort of Hangfire Client API User. Is there a way to simplify this internal communication between WebAPI and Hangfire .NET Core Console Application Background process by using SignalR? Ideally I would like to use secret string stored in shared database as configuration value and validate based on this string. Maybe I could create separate Hub for this internal communication and validate in **OnConnected** method? After validation I could use IHubContext to call the other hub, which communicates with frontend? However I'm not sure if this is correct idea.

Comment: Why are you using Hangfire in .Net-Core, Core has hosted services built in?

Comment: Additionally, why do you need an authentication token in the Background service?   Are you performing actions on their behalf.    Usually you can get around this by storing the identity information in a container and queue the information up with the task to give it a scope.   But running request on the users behalf in the background isn't always the best idea and can cause complications

Comment: @johnny5 my bad, that is actually hosted service, but in other project than Web API. I don't need to store token in Background service, what I want to say, that ideally I would like to call the Same Hub which is protected with [Authorize] attribute in Web API project, but I cannot do that without providing token. So I wondered maybe I could create separate hub for this communication between Hangfire Background process and WebAPI?

Comment: Hey,  Basically, you need to split the logic,  The Authorize attribute should be declared by the controller.  However internally, you should just be able to request the `IHubContext` from the DI container, and use that to push to your clients.  (I'm assuming this task  is to separate your pushing to client logic from the request  so you don't have to wait to send)